# Google Home report state request is working but not showing expected result?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I'm integrating google assistant with my application. The problem is when I send a report state request to assistant while inside a device screen in google home application, I get a 200 OK response with the requestId I'm sending, but the device screen doesn't update with the device state. (It gets updated after I go back and go to device screen again but that is done through query intent)

**Sample Request Body**

```
{  
   "payload" : {
      "devices" : {
         "states" : {
            "12364" : {
               "on" : true
                      }
                    }
                  }
               },
  "requestId" : "A7TNpoXlnG0OQWzpTvJAa4sjolAAt46q",
  "agentUserId" : "14556"
}
```

**Sample Response Body**

```
{ "requestId" : "A7TNpoXlnG0OQWzpTvJAa4sjolAAt46q" }
```

This is their documentation regarding the [report state](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state#deploy-report-state-dashboard).

I even deployed the report state dashboard locally to monitor the state changes but it doesn't update as well.

Can anyone point me in right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your question! This is a known issue and is the current expected behavior in the Google Home app. You can star this public issue to get updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139688477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of different Assistant surfaces with respect to Home Graph changes can vary, so it's best not to rely on looking for real-time UI changes in the Google Home app.

The [Report State Dashboard](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-dashboard/releases) noted in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state#deploy-report-state-dashboard) that you linked is a good way to validate the state you publish to Home Graph graphically. We also recently published an [AoG ProTips](https://medium.com/google-developers/aog-protips-inspecting-home-graph-503df93b7a91) episode on this topic that shows you how to do the same from the command line.

Neither of these methods will update automatically in real-time either, but you can refresh them after publishing a state change to verify the right data is in Home Graph.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I hope it will get fixed soon.